# About the mean values theorem and strictely increasing functions

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following question which I cannot find its proof:

Let us consider the following mean values theorem:

**Theorem**: Let $f:[a,b]→[a,b]$ be a continuous function on the closed interval $[a,b]$, and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$, where $a<b$. Then there exists some $c∈(a,b)$ such that

$$f′(c)= \frac{f(b)- f(a)}{b-a}$$

Assuming that  $f$ and $f'$  are strictely increasing functions. hence they are bijections from $[a,b]$ to itdelf.

My **question** is: Given any $c∈(a,b)$ can we find $u,v$ in $[a,b]$ such that

$$f′(c)= \frac{f(u)- f(v)}{u-v}$$

The same question if one fix $u$ or $v$.

Comment: Note that $f$ is continuously differentiable: $f'$ can have only jump discontinuity, because it is strictely increasing. But by Darboux's theorem $f'$ has the intermediate value property. Thus $f'$ is continuous. Therefore the linked result can be applied.